# How can I fix my REST view to PATCH and serialize updates to an ArrayField() in my model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a view that is used to update a field in my model. It's represented as follows: `stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField())`

Each value in the ArrayField is separated by commas.

I used a custom serializer method to allow for my backend to separate the elements in my PATCH `obj` by commas.

- `serializers.py`:

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
        # convert list to string
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
        return super().to_internal_value(self, data)


class StockListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock_list = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ("stock_list",)
```

Below is my view that I use, the URL's are linked up correctly, however I'm setting up my view wrong:

- `view.py:`

```
class EditBucketSymbols(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StockListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Bucket.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(Bucket, pk=item)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item = BucketDetail.get_object(self)
        data = request.data
        item.stock_list = data.get("stock_list", item.stock_list)
        serializer = StockListSerializer(data=item.stock_list,  partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is the PATCH error I get:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure why my view is expecting a dictionary, I only want the users to PATCH the arrayfield known as `stock_list` with the data they input.

Appreciate any debugging assistance here to get my PATCH view working properly as expected.

Comment: Please help to show your data request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change the `super()` method calling of ***`to_internal_value(...)`*** method (you were not calling it correctly)

```
class StringArrayField(serializers.ListField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")
        return super().to_internal_value(data) # update here
```

and then, use the **`generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView`** *"as-is"*, because, you don't need any alterations to the view (at-least the minimal case you have given in the OP)

So, your view will become,

```
class EditBucketSymbols(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StockListSerializer
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()
```

This will let you update the data with ease and keep in mind that the DRF expect the data in the following format,

```
{
    "stock_list":"this,is,patch,request,test"
}
```

**Example Result ScreenShot**
[image: Example Result ScreenShot]

Comment: Ah this is great @JPG! Many thanks for the help and explanations you have added to this post.